# PXC Node still not starting after full sync from donor

Tags: mysql, percona, galera

I have a node in the PXC that stopped, and now after a full sync from donor, it still does not start. The error log message from the donor is provided below:

When i ran the "show status like 'wsrep%'\G" on the donor node, it showed that the wsrep_local_state_comment changed from DONOR/DESYNCED to SYNCED. This i believe indicates that the full sync is complete. But i am not sure why the node won't start.

```
 2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: cda64f2b-74a8-11e5-b965-36b9ac108f08 from 9 (db-kdb-5-2)

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:

        version    = 3,

        component  = PRIMARY,

        conf_id    = 101,

        members    = 10/11 (joined/total),

        act_id     = 4281851091,

        last_appl. = 4281850971,

        protocols  = 0/7/3 (gcs/repl/appl),

        group UUID = 3248f155-08ac-11e4-a36a-1347fdb518d6

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [53, 53]

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 3248f155-08ac-11e4-a36a-1347fdb518d6:4281851091, view# 102: Primary, number of nodes: 11, my index: 0, protocol version 3

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 7 (3, 2)

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 4281851091, protocol version: 3

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: Member 9.0 (db-node-1) requested state transfer from ‘db-node1'. Selected 0.0 (db-node-1)(SYNCED) as donor.

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: Shifting SYNCED -> DONOR/DESYNCED (TO: 4281851185)

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.

2015-10-17 16:26:46 13833 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'donor' --address ‘192.168.2.51:4444/xtrabackup_sst//1' --auth ‘user:pass' --socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' --defaults-group-suffix ''   '' --gtid '3248f155-08ac-11e4-a36a-1347fdb518d6:4281851185''

2015-10-17 16:26:47 13833 [Note] WSREP: sst_donor_thread signaled with 0

WSREP_SST: [INFO] Streaming with xbstream (20151017 16:26:47.542)

WSREP_SST: [INFO] Using socat as streamer (20151017 16:26:47.546)

WSREP_SST: [INFO] Using /tmp/tmp.ZQBX8Kolho as innobackupex temporary directory (20151017 16:26:47.560)

WSREP_SST: [INFO] Streaming GTID file before SST (20151017 16:26:47.567)

WSREP_SST: [INFO] Evaluating xbstream -c ${INFO_FILE} | socat -u stdio TCP:10.1.5.51:4444; RC=( ${PIPESTATUS[@]} ) (20151017 16:26:47.570)

WSREP_SST: [INFO] Sleeping before data transfer for SST (20151017 16:26:47.577)

2015-10-17 16:26:47 13833 [Note] WSREP: (1e75ae0c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off

WSREP_SST: [INFO] Streaming the backup to joiner at 192.168.2.51 4444 (20151017 16:26:57.582)

WSREP_SST: [INFO] Evaluating innobackupex --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf  --defaults-group=mysqld --no-version-check  $tmpopts $INNOEXTRA --galera-info --stream=$sfmt $itmpdir 2>${DATA}/innobackup.backup.log | socat -u stdio TCP:192.168.2.51:4444; RC=( ${PIPESTATUS[@]} ) (20151017 16:26:57.586)

2015/10/17 16:26:59 socat[4849] E write(3, 0x17741d0, 8192): Broken pipe

WSREP_SST: [ERROR] innobackupex finished with error: 1.  Check /var/lib/mysql//innobackup.backup.log (20151017 16:26:59.875)

WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Cleanup after exit with status:22 (20151017 16:26:59.879)

WSREP_SST: [INFO] Cleaning up temporary directories (20151017 16:26:59.884)

2015-10-17 16:26:59 13833 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read from: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'donor' --address ‘192.168.2.51:4444/xtrabackup_sst//1' --auth ‘user:pass' --socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' --defaults-group-suffix ''   '' --gtid '3248f155-08ac-11e4-a36a-1347fdb518d6:4281851185'

2015-10-17 16:26:59 13833 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'donor' --address ‘192.168.2.51:4444/xtrabackup_sst//1' --auth ‘user:pass' --socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' --defaults-group-suffix ''   '' --gtid '3248f155-08ac-11e4-a36a-1347fdb518d6:4281851185': 22 (Invalid argument)

2015-10-17 16:26:59 13833 [ERROR] WSREP: Command did not run: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'donor' --address ’192.168.2.51:4444/xtrabackup_sst//1' --auth ‘user:pass' --socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' --defaults-group-suffix ''   '' --gtid '3248f155-08ac-11e4-a36a-1347fdb518d6:4281851185'

2015-10-17 16:26:59 13833 [Warning] WSREP: 0.0 (db-node-2): State transfer to 9.0 (db-node-1) failed: -22 (Invalid argument)

2015-10-17 16:26:59 13833 [Note] WSREP: Shifting DONOR/DESYNCED -> JOINED (TO: 4281853007)

2015-10-17 16:26:59 13833 [Note] WSREP: (1e75ae0c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') address 'tcp://192.168.1.4:4567' pointing to uuid 1e75ae0c is blacklisted, skipping

2015-10-17 16:26:59 13833 [Note] WSREP: (1e75ae0c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') address 'tcp://192.168.1.4.:4567' pointing to uuid 1e75ae0c is blacklisted, skipping

2015-10-17 16:26:59 13833 [Note] WSREP: (1e75ae0c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') address 'tcp://192.168.1.4:4567' pointing to uuid 1e75ae0c is blacklisted, skipping

2015-10-17 16:26:59 13833 [Note] WSREP: (1e75ae0c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') address 'tcp://192.168.1.4:4567' pointing to uuid 1e75ae0c is blacklisted, skipping
```

Comment: Read again: *2015-10-17 16:26:59 13833 [Warning] WSREP: 0.0 (db-node-2): State transfer to 9.0 (db-node-1) failed: -22 (Invalid argument)*  The donor is done with the sync because it failed, not because it succeeded.

Comment: But why would the SST be failing? I am using xtrabackup-v2

Comment: It seems almost as if you did not read what you have posted.  *WSREP_SST: [ERROR] innobackupex finished with error: 1.  Check /var/lib/mysql//innobackup.backup.log (20151017 16:26:59.875)*   Checking this log file may offer possible explanations.